# Formalizing playing with function domains. If $f(x + 3) = g(x^2)$, then $f(x) = g( (x-3)^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I came across a question that let $f(x + 3) = g(x^2)$, and playing around with the domain I concluded that $f(x) = g( (x-3)^2)$ . My question is:

> What is the formal name/ method of what I'm doing (playing around with domains)?

Because the way I figured it out was very informal. I just noted that:

$f(4) = g(1)$

$f(5) = g(4)$

$f(6) = g(9)$

...

and figured out the pattern connecting the number pairs $4-1, 5-4, 6-9$, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $t=x+3$ then $x=t-3$ so $$f(t) = g((t-3)^2)$$

And since the linear map is $x\mapsto x+3$ is surjective, you can write again the same variable, so $$f(x) = g((x-3)^2)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x+3)=g(x^2)$$

$$f((x-3)+3)=g((x-3)^2)$$

Hence

$$f(x)=g((x-3)^2)$$